# Log Error in Nested Fragments on View Pager : No view found for id

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that Contains view pager.there are three fragments in that Main fragment they are Fragment A,Fragment B,Fragment C. Upto this code runs properly.
Then i added a new Fragment and called via Fragment A then i got the error in the Log

**No view found for id 0x7f0d0083 (com.app.sanyog:id/frame) for fragment                SearchPlaces{289bf4e #0 id=0x7f0d0083}**

**Main Fragment:**

```
/**
 * Created by Admin on 04-06-2015.
 */
public class ContentFragment_Flight_Bkg extends Fragment  {


    private View view;
    public ViewPager pager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_fragment_flight,container,false);
        TabsPagerAdapter adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
         pager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

         pager.setAdapter(adapter);




        return view;
    }


}
```

**Pager Adapter**

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    // Tab Titles
    private String tabtitles[] = new String[] { "One Way", "Round Trip", "Multicity" };
    Context context;

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {

            // Open FragmentTab1.java
            case 0:
                OneWayTab fragmenttab1 = new OneWayTab();
                return fragmenttab1;

            // Open FragmentTab2.java
            case 1:
                RoundTripTab fragmenttab2 = new RoundTripTab();
                return fragmenttab2;

            // Open FragmentTab3.java
            case 2:
                MultiCityTab fragmenttab3 = new MultiCityTab();
                return fragmenttab3;


        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabtitles[position];
    }

}
```

**Fragment A**

```
public class OneWayTab extends Fragment {



    private LinearLayout oneway_source,oneway_destiantion;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the view from fragmenttab3.xml
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_one_way_tab, container, false);

        oneway_source = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.oneway_source_layout);
        oneway_destiantion = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.oneway_destination_layout);

        oneway_source.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SearchPlaces fragment_Flight= new SearchPlaces();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction_Flight = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction_Flight.replace(R.id.frame,fragment_Flight,"FLight_booking");
                fragmentTransaction_Flight.commit();

            }
        });
        oneway_destiantion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Utils.showToast(getActivity(),"Destiantion");
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

**New Fragment (Called from Fragment A)**

```
public class SearchPlaces extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the view from fragmenttab1.xml
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_search_places, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: fragment added on layout so where is your layout

Comment: which layout you want main fragment layout or fragment A or New frragment

Comment: i am not getting which layout you are talking about